# Cannot start workling_starling_client in rails production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, god, workling, starling-server

I was using **god** to start and monitor my starling and workling daemons.

Works awesome on **development** machine but "workling_starling_client" refuses to start on my **production** machine.

Answer (score 3):

I realized that by explicitly doing

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

my workling-starling-client started up properly.

Therefore I had to declare **RAILS_ENV** variable before issuing **god config file**

```
RAILS_ENV=production god -d config/monitor_daemons.god -t
```

I'm also using the variable to start **starling daemon** in **production port**

```
STARLING_PORT = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production' ? '-p 15151' : ''

God.watch do |w|
  ...
  w.start = "starling -d -P log/starling.pid -q log/ #{STARLING_PORT}"
  ...
end

God.watch do |w|
  ...
  w.start = "script/workling_starling_client start"
  ...
```

end